# Compile a C# visual studio console application in mono (mac)

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I am pretty new to mono and C# so this is probably a simple question, but i cannot find the answer.
I need to compile a C# visual studio console application on my mac. I thought mono would be right for that purpose. I don't know which file to compile and took program.cs (where my main function is) or should i compile Project.csproj.
When i run

```
gmcs Program.cs
```

I get

```
Program.cs(17,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Oplossing' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(129,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Order' could not be found. Are    you missing an assembly reference?
```

What en how should i compile?

Comment: Try compiling *all* the source files in one go. Or just use MonoDevelop.

Comment: How would i compile all source files at ones?

Comment: Something like `gmcs *.cs` ? Look at the documentation for `gmcs` maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via xbuild, you should be able to compile csproj directly,

http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are working on a system without a ui, (since you are targetting macos you have a ui) download and install Monodevelop and open the visual studio project with that.

Otherwise check the (g) mcs documentation
The way to use it is already in te comments here

Note: you do NOT have to recompile your app on MacOs to run it on MacOS, just copy the exe (assembly) to your mac and execute it with mono